# ¿Es posible seleccionar una clase anidada con css?

Tags: html, css

intentaba modificar un elemento pero tenían el mismo nombre de clase anidado

```
<div class="wrap">
    <p>primer div</p>
    <div class="wrap">
        <p>segundo div</p>
        <div class="wrap">
           <p>tercer div</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

¿Cómo podría modificar el segundo div con una hoja css sin afectar el primero ni al ultimo div de la clase "wrap"?

Comment: Revisa la documentación de los selectores CSS https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: primer elemento .wrap, segundo elemento, .wrap .wrap y este afecta al tercero, solo para el tercero podrias usar .wrap .wrap .wrap

Comment: El problema de usar .wrap .wrap es que eso se cumple tanto entre primer y segundo div, como entre segundo y tercero, si utiliza este método y por ejemplo cambia el color de la letra, cambiaría el color tanto en el segundo como tercer div.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras, primeramente se debe tomar todos los elementos con clase .wrap que sean hijos de un .wrap, puede ser de la siguiente manera

```
.wrap > .wrap {
  color: red;
}
```

O también puede ser:

```
.wrap:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

Y la segunda parte es que los hijos de estos elementos que tengan la clase .wrap (y los hijos sucesivos) tengan propiedades diferentes:

```
.wrap > .wrap > .wrap {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: En principio tanto la primera como la segunda opción cambiarían el color tanto del segundo como el tercer div. Esto es porque el segundo es padre del primero y  manteniendo la misma estructura el tercero es padre del segundo.

Answer (score 0):

En general se aplica clases cuando se quiere afectar a todos los elementos tengan esa clase, si bien hay selectores que podrían ayudar a alcanzar elementos hijos, debido a que la estructura es un tercer div dentro de un segundo, y luego ese segundo dentro del primero teniendo todos la misma clase, en muchos casos lo que se haga intentando seleccionar el segundo afecta al segundo y tercer div.

Para resolver esto se podría poner un id único al elemento que se desea modificar y luego se podría hacer algo así:

```css
.wrap {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#secondWrap > p {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
#secondWrap > span {
    color: red;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
#secondWrap > a {
    color: orange;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <p>primer div</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <span>prueba</span>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">Ir a Google</a>
      <div class="wrap" id="secondWrap">
        <p>segundo div</p>
        <p>Test</p>
        <span>prueba</span>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">Ir a Google</a>
        <div class="wrap">
          <p>tercer div</p>
          <p>Test</p>
          <span>prueba</span>
          <a href="https://www.google.com">Ir a Google</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

En este ejemplo se aplica color de fondo para todos los div con clase wrap, y se le aplica estílos específicos a los diferentes elementos que están dentro del elemento con id secondWrap.

El segundo div entonces quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="wrap" id="secondWrap">
```

---

También es posible lograr lo mismo agregando una segunda clase al segundo div, sería de la siguiente manera:

**En HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap secondWrap">
```

**En CSS:**

```
.wrap {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.wrap.secondWrap > p {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.wrap.secondWrap > span {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.wrap.secondWrap > a {
  color: orange;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

En este caso se está seleccionando al elemento que tiene la clase wrap y la clase secondWrap.

---

Por último hay selectores de CSS que pueden ser útiles como el > para los childs y otros pseudo como nth-child, first-child, y otros.

Link a documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: También directamente puede poner `.wrap>.wrap>.wrap {/*css aquí*/}`, eso se aplicaría solo a la clase wrap anidada dentro de otra clase wrap anidada dentro de otra clase wrap

Comment: El problema con eso es que se cumple para el div 1 y 2 y también  para el div 2 y 3 por la estructura que tiene.. Por lo que se afectaría en este caso al div 2 y div 3.. E incluso esto es si de acuerdo a tu ejemplo fueran 2 .wrap, pero en tu ejemplo estaría afectando al tercer div únicamente.

Comment: Leí mal la pregunta, efectivamente si se quiere afectar únicamente al segundo esto no sería válido, disculpa la confusión!

Answer (score 0):

Aquí dejo un ejemplo sencillo con el que se puede ver/entender el uso de clases anidadas y descendientes directos.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```css
/* Todos los .wrap */
.wrap {
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* Todos los .wrap que vayan seguidos de un "título" */
p + .wrap {
  font-style: italic;
}

/* Primer .wrap que encontramos */
.wrap:first-child {
  background: red;
}
/* Tras localizar el primer elemento, buscamos un descendiente directo con clase .wrap */
.wrap:first-child > .wrap {
  background: green;
}
/* Anterior ejemplo, localizando el tercer descendiente */
.wrap:first-child > .wrap > .wrap {
  background: blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <p>primer div</p>
    <div class="wrap">
        <p>segundo div</p>
        <div class="wrap">
           <p>tercer div</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```